# I want to customize wp.media (the wordpress admin uploader) in order to change the file name but only in video custom post type

Tags: uploads, plupload

I want to customize the wordpress default admin interface uploader: wp.media.

I already created a custom post type named "video" and I added a wp.media element which permits to upload the corresponding video for each video custom post.

But I want, for the custom post type named "video" , to automatically change the uploaded file name and add ".hidden." inside the file name. (for instance: great-video.mp4 -> great-video.hidden.mp4).

I guess I can do that easily with a filter in the part of the php which upload the files, but the problem is that is would add ".hidden." strings not only to video uploaded files but also to any uploaded files in the admin interface, which I don't want.

My idea would be to add a POST data (for instance: video_hidden=true) when sending the file but only in the custom post type video in the uploader interface, and then in the php filter I check if POST video_hidden is set to true, and in this case add ".hidden." in the file name.

But how to add this POST data only in upload of this custom post type named "video"?